# Serverless framework running Java code hangs

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I'm running Serverless 2.15.0 with Node 14.15.0.  I've tried installing both with `npm i -g` and by using the `curl` script in the tutorial.  I have Maven 3.6.3 installed

When I try to run a simple Java "hello world" function locally, I get this message:

`Serverless: Building Java bridge, first invocation might take a bit longer.`

Then Serverless just hangs.  No error message, nothing.  When I try to run with `SLS_DEBUG=*`, there are no messages after that point.

The only thing I've been able to Google is [this](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2864), but there isn't any resolution to the problem.  The other thing I've found is [this](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4415) but there seems to be no `java` directory where Serverless is installed, so I can't manually compile the pom file.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that they moved the path of the java runtime wrapper. Base paths differ regarding install location.

**NVM (global installation)**

```
cd ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invoke-local/runtime-wrappers/java
mvn package
```

**NPM (global installation)**

```
cd ~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/runtimeWrappers/java
mvn package
```

**Homebrew**

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/serverless/2.29.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/runtimeWrappers/java
mvn package
```

Replace `2.29.0` with installed serverless version.

Comment: any hint how to fix it?

Comment: @levo4ka Just run commands mentioned above. cd DIR + mvn package.